# Access-Control-Allow-Origin at heroku seems like not work

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku, sinatra

I have a sinatra app at **heroku** and can't make it

```
get '/fdsfdsfd' do
  uri = URI.parse('https://fdsfdsfds')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  res = http.request(req)

  # headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  # headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  # headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] ="accept, authorization, origin"

  response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] ="accept, authorization, origin"

  res.body

end
```

Inspecting a response, it see that the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` exists, but **yet** making an ajax request from my javascript script, I get an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `https://fdsfdsfds`. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Maybe it's the issue of heroku? Or what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

And here's a log from curl (partially):

```
> GET /something HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: something.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization, origin
< Content-Length: 2638
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
* Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.4/2015-12-16) is not blacklisted
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.4/2015-12-16)
< Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 12:51:09 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
....body
```

Comment: "Response to preflight request" — You have a `get` handler but the browser is making an `options` request.

Comment: @Quentin, what's options request? moreover, "response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"" includes options.

Comment: If you use google to look up what "preflight" means in the context of CORS (or Ajax in general) then you'll see what the OPTIONS request is.

Comment: @Quentin, updated my question.

Comment: `"response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS""` might include options but `get '/fdsfdsfd' do` does not.

Comment: @Quentin, how to fix it?

Comment: You make the server respond to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: @Quentin 1) why do you say **...options but get '/fdsfdsfd' do does not.** if I set the headers exactly in this method 2) how to make the server respond to options?

Comment: Becase putting `get` at the front, presumably means "This is a handler for GET requests". I would *assume* you put `options` at the front to write a controller for OPTION requests, but I don't know the framework you are using so that is just speculation.

Comment: see where you got `get '/fdsfdsfd' do` ... you also need code for `options '/fdsfdsfd' do` - so you respond to an `options` request (which is how CORS requests are preflighted) - Also, most `get` requests shouldn't need preflighting, unless you have some custom header in your request

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks.